# Prediction based on repeated measure with binary outcome

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, survival, logit, binary-data

I'd like to make a prediction about a subject's likelihood that a certain outcome will occur based on a series of measurements taken over time.

The easiest way to explain the problem is as follows. Imagine that I'm tracking an individual over time to generate a probability of ever getting lung cancer.

The training data would look something like this with the outcome being "has cancer"

```
ID           age   cigarettes  asbestos   lung        has cancer
                     per day   exposure   capacity
S_1           5       0           N          20             N
S_1           17      20          N          50             N
S_1           31      50          N          30             N
S_1           42      0           N          40             Y
S_2           15      0           N          55             N
S_2           37      0           N          45             N
S_3           5       3           Y          15             N
S_3           50      0           Y          30             Y
etc...
```

The test data would be taken before an individual has gotten cancer and would predict their probability of getting cancer at any time in the future.

What's the best way to model this?

I'm currently experimenting with mixed models, treating this like a repeated measure problem. However, the dependent variable (whether someone ever gets cancer) is not being repeatedly measured over time. Instead it is fixed, so it seemed this might not be the best approach. As you can see there are additional problems of the dataset being unbalanced, with measures taken at irregular periods.

**EDIT 1:** Would it be better to think of this in terms of survival analysis? I assume the event in this case would be contracting cancer. If so how do I deal with deaths not related to lung cancer?

**Edit 2:** I'm thinking now of using a joint model that combines a mixed effect model with a survival analysis model: http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=packages:cran:jm. Any thoughts as to whether this might work for my problem? It seemed that I could use the hazard function to get a prediction for likelihood of ever getting cancer.

Comment: Not sure why you say the dependent variable is not repeatedly measured.  For the subject with ID = S_1, it looks like there are 4 measurements.

Comment: Because I'm trying to predict whether an individual will ever get cancer. So the true outcome would be all Ys if the individual ever gets cancer and all Ns otherwise. In the table above, this would translate into all Ys for S_1, all Ns for S_2, all Ys for S_3.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'll venture a guess that mixed models are appropriate.  Your primary concern seems to be that the response is fixed, within-subject.  One way of looking at this is that the within-subject variance is zero. I suspect that this fits in with mixed models as a special case, but here is where my knowledge ends.

Comment: That's what I figured. I'm trying to piece together what the correlation structure should look like. It's not going to be autocorrelated as the within subject prediction is always the same, but what is it then... Thanks a lot for the feedback.

Comment: Look into time-dependent covariates and extended Cox models.